# How to cut a 1GB section off of a very large text file (98GB)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, file-management

I managed to generate a 98GB log file during an overnight test. I can't do anything with a 98GB file. I wanted to cut it into smaller parts originally, so I tried 7-zip but I don't actually have enough room left on my disk (probably because there is 100GB file there now...). So I want to cut off just the 1GB section off the end. Is this possible?

It is just a text file that has timestamps and some data afterwards, and I don't really care if the first line in a file gets cut/mangled. Anything built into Windows 10 that I can use?

Comment: I don't think there are any built-in solutions. But first you may try resizing the pagefile, or simply disabling hiberfil.sys and you'll immediately have a few GBs to run `tail` on the log. After that just remove the huge log file and resize the *.sys files if needed. Or if you have another drive just store the output file there

Comment: @phuclv, thanks. I used Bob's suggestion and apparently my data was within the first GB, the rest was just exceptions. The only other drive I have available is a network drive, and writing 98GB, even in chunks, is pretty wild!

Comment: in that case it's just easier to [call `SetEndOfFile`](https://superuser.com/q/299329/241386) to truncate the file

Comment: @phuclv, yes, it's easier if I would have known that I didn't need the 97GB at the end. However, I wasn't sure where the problem was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might also be doable with built-in cmdlets, but I'd be wary of running `Get-Content` on any files over 100 MB. If you want to try, you might want [an equivalent for `tail`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4426442/unix-tail-equivalent-command-in-windows-powershell). I am uncertain if those are smart enough to skip ahead, or if they try to read every line from the start and only display the last X lines. Obviously the latter approach would take a while if it's trying to read and skip 90+ GB.

If you don't care about tools built into Windows, I believe the GNU `tail` implementation is smarter. This can be run from WSL or one of the many ports.

Sticking with pure PowerShell/.NET scripting, I'll adapt a [previous](https://superuser.com/a/1295082/117590) PowerShell script designed to split a single large file. This script was written to use 4 kB blocks, minimising memory usage. We can first *seek* to the correct location (a nearly instantaneous operation) and copy from there. For simplicity, no parsing for the next/previous *line* break is done; we're simply jumping to a specific byte (even mid-line).

If you'd prefer to seek a certain distance from the beginning, you could e.g. substitute `$seekLoc = 97GB` and `$seekOrigin = "Begin"`, and maybe `$copyLen = 10GB` to be safe and not miss the end.

```
$inFile = "foo.txt"
$outFile = "bar.txt"
$seekLoc = -1GB
$seekOrigin = "End"
$copyLen = 1GB

# need to sync .NET CurrentDirectory with PowerShell CurrentDirectory
# https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18862716/current-directory-from-a-dll-invoked-from-powershell-wrong
[Environment]::CurrentDirectory = Get-Location
# 4k is a fairly typical and 'safe' chunk size
# partial chunks are handled below
$bytes = New-Object byte[] 4096

$inReader = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($inFile)
$inReader.Seek($seekLoc, $seekOrigin)

# better to use functions but a flag is easier in a simple script
$finished = $false

$bytesToRead = $copyLen

# Just like File::OpenWrite except CreateNew instead to prevent overwriting existing files
$outWriter = New-Object System.IO.FileStream "$outFile",CreateNew,Write,None

while ($bytesToRead) {
    # read up to 4k at a time, but no more than the remaining bytes from copyLen
    $bytesRead = $inReader.Read($bytes, 0, [Math]::Min($bytes.Length, $bytesToRead))

    # 0 bytes read means we've reached the end of the input file
    if (!$bytesRead) {
        break
    }

    $bytesToRead -= $bytesRead

    $outWriter.Write($bytes, 0, $bytesRead)
}

# dispose closes the stream and releases locks
$outWriter.Dispose()

$inReader.Dispose()
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Bob. It worked great. The data I wanted was actually in the first GB, the rest (all 97GB) was filled with the same exception over and over (not my software) until it filled up my SSD and crashed before I came in. Exciting!

Comment: note that this writes to a different file, so it won't work if there's not enough 1GB free space. In most cases the logging process often fails to write because there's no space left on the drive and you don't actually get the log right before it crashed

Comment: @phuclv. There was enough space for a 1GB chunk. Realistically in most cases it should be possible to clear out some space on the drive to save a chunk into. Using `tail` as you suggested allowed me to see some lines at the end, but without knowing how much data was safe to cut off, I couldn't just truncate the file.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the
[The V File Viewer](https://www.fileviewer.com/)
to easily view such large files with success.
This solution will not require much disk space, and the viewer is very fast.

The V File Viewer is trialware with 30 days trial period, then
$20 that includes 6 years of free upgrades.
If you need to analyze such large text files from time to time,
it might be worth the price.
I paid it and consider it an excellent investment.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I prefer solutions where I don't have to install third party software though, so I'm accepting Bob's answer.